# How does one trust a ConTeXt installation?

Tags: context, security

I want to download the ConTeXt source code from a GitHub mirror, such that I can select a version by checking out a commit.
This is where the problem of verifying that this code hasn't been tampered with comes into play.
In essence, I want to verify my installations using signatures ("this code was signed by Hans Hagen, and has not been tampered with").

This problem also seems to hold for the scripts provided by the contextgarden mirrors. How do I trust these haven't been tampered with?

Comment: Hans don't sign the code ...

Comment: Unfortunately, in the TeX world nothing is signed.

Comment: How does anyone know that the "signature" has not been forged?

Comment: @PeterWilson I think you're looking for a (definition of) web of trust, although I could be wrong here. If you're seeking a more practical answer: PGP is (as far as I can tell) the ubiquitous solution, with GnuPG being one of the most commonly used implementations.